# Console closing instantly not going through the code

Tags: c#, methods, console-application

Just been learning C# methods on SOLO LEARN,  i'm on method parameters the app have it's own compiler and totally different from visual studio so i can't get this code to work. When i try to run the console it closes instantly even tho i have Console.Read();

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


        }

        void myFunc(int x)
        {
            int result = x / 2;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Main` is not running anbything

Comment: where are you calling you myFunc ?.

Comment: Because you do not do anything in your Main() method. That is the starting point of your application.

Comment: add myFunc in main method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call anything from `Main()`. Call `myFunc()` from `Main()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myFunc(4);
}
```

Also you should make `myFunc()` to be `static`:

```
static void myFunc(int x)
```

**OR**

You can create instance of `Program` and call this function without making `myFunc()` static (simply change your `Main()` method):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.myFunc(4);
}
```

Comment: It says there's no argument given that corresponds to 'x'

Comment: I have done those and i assumed im just doing it wrong.. It says An object reference is required for non-static, method or property 'Program.myFunc(int)

Comment: put `static` before `void myFunc(int x)` so, it should be `static void myFunc(int x)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the function you have created inside your main. 
In a console app `static void Main(string[] args)` is the function where application starts.
So, in order to have your application started you need to execute your `myFunc(int x)` function inside it.

Make the changes like below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           myFunc(4); //You need to put an integer here              
        }
```